# React streaming audio file gets cached

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a function which creates a new file in the back-end but the `<PlaySound />` component keeps playing the old sound file and not the updated one. The sound file has the same name/path it just has different content.

I tried having the `row.text` as the key so it would force the component to update when the description of the file updates. I also tried generating a `GUID` as seed for the url, and also to use `no-cache` headers but nothing seems to work...

```
<PlaySound key={ row.text } path={ row.location.path } filename={ row.location.filename } />
```

This is the PlaySound component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
import { genUID } from '../../../helpers/helperFunctions';
    
class PlaySound extends Component
    {
        playSound(path, filename) {
            var endpoint = "http://0.0.0.0:8001/api/stream"
            var url = endpoint + "?path=" + path + "&filename=" + filename + "&seed=" + genUID()
            var audio = new Audio(url);
            console.log(audio);
            audio.load();
            audio.play();        
        }
    
        render() 
        {
            return (
                <div>
                    <span onClick={() => this.playSound(this.props.path, this.props.filename)}>&#9658;</span>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    
export default PlaySound
```

Here is my nodejs/express streaming implementation...

```
app.get(API_VERSION + '/stream', (req, res) =>
{
  const filepath = req.query.path;
  const filename = req.query.filename;

  const file = '/app/audioExport/' + filepath + filename;

  try
  {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
      'Pragma': 'no-cache',
      'Content-Type': 'audio/wav',
    });
    const rstream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    rstream.pipe(res);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({error: error})
  }
});
```

** Edit ** Found a related question with no answer.
[Reload Audio Cache without Refreshing Page JS/NODE.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74219111/reload-audio-cache-without-refreshing-page-js-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be useful to check the whole flow step-by-step. Changing URL with `seed` parameter is a good idea to 100% guarantee that caches is not used. It is hard to say if it is working correctly here. What I would do is

1. Check Chrome DevTools for generated requests. In the Network section it will clearly say size and either it comes from cache or not
2. It is possible that your Node.js server is using the same file. How do you generate new one? Can it be race-conditioned and you are trying to read it before it is updated

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer- 1. everything is the same except for the date... I guess it comes from cache. 2. I am sure that the file is different because the front end tells me when the new file is created. I guess it has something to do with express cache? Any other suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you led me on the right track and was able to resolve my problem.

Comment: Actually, the situation improved but files still get cached randomly. I tried changing the etag to the see but the files still keep on caching... Any other suggestion?

Comment: Resolved. I discovered a prop not passing through to the PlaySound even though the UI updates.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by following this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39407519/1617800

By adding the following headers to express now the file does not cache...

```
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Expires', "access plus 1 second");
  req.header['if-none-match'] = '';
  req.header['if-modified-since'] = '';
```

and also added a unique etag that generated based on the seed

```
app.set('etag', res.set('etag', req.query.seed));
```

The app is for intranet purposes so caching doesn't matter so much in this context. Still, I'll apply the headers only to the `/stream` endpoint.